# Valuate complex number expressions

Tags: expression, evaluation, complex-numbers

For valuate arithmetic expression I use the Donal Knuth algorithm, which convert the expression to postfix and the use the postfix stack to resolve the expression. I'm wondering, there is something similar for complex number expressions?

Something which can do for example: ((2+8i)*(12+3i)^(1/2))/34+21i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same techniques. You just define the operations you can perform and you store the operand type information together with a value on the stack.

Comment: I choose yours since it's simpler

Answer (score 1):

Define 'i' as unary operator, that multiplies the last operand in stack by 'i';
You can associate each value in stack with type, but that can be handled also by always pushing two numbers: the real component and an explicit zero.

Then (2+8i) is handled as

```
push 2 [and 0]
push 8 [and 0]
push i
-> pop 8 and 0
-> push 0 and 8
push +
-> pop 0 and 8
-> pop 2 and 0
push 2 and 8
```

I think this could then handle expressions as (2+(2+2)i), but also (2+2i)i,